After reporting some errors about disk quotas, parts of the GeoServer web are not working
The GeoServer I'm using is version 2.20.0 deployed with docker.
Today it prompts on the web home page:

Unable to read disk quota information, the disk quota subsystem is disabled, please reconfigure Could not find a quota store named HSQL

So I turned up the quota in the disk quota settings and saved the settings and the error disappeared, but it still seems to be a problem.

Also I can't get to the three pages Server Status, Layer Preview and Layers.
The logs are just full of

WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: {0}


You have probably trashed the on disk store of quotas by changing it while it was in an unexpected state. Restart the server and all may be well.
